# Why does my blender not open?

Tags: error

When I downloaded Blender version 2.91.0 and opened it, the application would start loading but then it would close on its own. I didn't even see the starting or home page for blender. From what I gathered the problem was EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. I've uninstalled and reinstalled, and also tried to download different versions, but I don't know why they keep sending me to the download page for version 2.91.0. I'm using a computer Windows 10, can someone please help me.

Comment: The first step when this happens is usually to update your graphics drivers. Try updating and see if that fixes it.

Comment: you can download older versions here: https://download.blender.org/release/